struts1 issue for java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward.setContextRelative(Z)V
I am working on legacy application which still uses the struts basic jars and unfortunately we cant replace these jar though we can upgrade the jar versions.
I am facing below error on JSP load...
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:127)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward.setContextRelative(Z)V
    at org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction.execute(ForwardAction.java:151)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    ... 40 more

The struts library used in project as follows
struts-1.1.jar
struts-core-1.3.10.jar
struts-el-1.3.10.jar
struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar

Please can you suggest what's going wrong here

This is almost always a version mismatch between your build and deployment environments.

i didn't find any version mismatch here

There's a mess of libraries different versions of Struts. You need to add only dependencies required for the application. If you use Struts 1.3.0, then only those dependencies are required. But if you have both

struts-1.1.jar
struts-core-1.3.10.jar

in the lib folder then you get an error

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward.setContextRelative(Z)V

The method that is looked up belongs to another jar which is omitted because the class ActionForward is already loaded by the classloader.
The latest of Struts 1 EOL release is 1.3.10 which you can download here.
If you using Maven or any other building system to build your application then you can check this repository. This also listed available dependencies and CVEs for the artifacts.
